# how to specify the custom python path when using visual studio code to debug

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code(1.77.1) to debbugging a python application, how to specify the python path in `launch.json`? I have tried like this:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/path",
```

but did not work. I also read the docs https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments and created the .env in project folder. add the python path like this:

```
PYTHONPATH = /opt/python
```

still could not work. What should I do to specify the custom python path? I also tried this:

```
"pythonPath": "/path/to/custom/python",
```

this is the `launch.json` file right now:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: FastAPI",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "uvicorn",
            "python.pythonPath": "/path",
            "args": [
                "main:app",
                "--port=9002"
            ],
            "jinja": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `python.pythonPath` is the path relative to the workspace folder of the python interpreter or the absolute path of the python interpreter, you need to set it in `settings.json`

Comment: where exactly is the python you want to use? give us an absolute path. What _exactly_ did you set in `python.pythonPath`?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the [***python***](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_python) option in *launch.json*.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "python": "E:\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then use the green triangle button on the **Run and Debug** panel to start debugging.

[image]